# How to find class definition knowing an object in Python in PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, boto3, boto

boto libraries have a lot of classes with similar names and different functionalities and vice versa (different names but same functionalities). I would like to track, which one is used in some specific case. Suppose I see an object in the debugger and it is shown as being of type `s3.Bucket`. How to find it's definition?

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on the class or method.

**Update**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> on the object definition and after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> on class definition.

Comment: I can't click it until I know it

Comment: @Dims Do you want to find the class in the source code of library?

Comment: This is exactly what I want. The same if I would ctrl-click the class name if I had it.

Comment: @Dims Ctrl + Click on object definition. Ctrl + Click on class definition.

Comment: Object came to a function and defined as a parameter name only.